# Testing EF data access with a Test DB data access

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing

I've done some of research today but I've not found any appropriate answer to my question.
I've inherited an ASP.NET MVC project where there's no sign of unit test. I've created all my repository using DI and I've separated the logic business from the data access (almost everywhere)

Now I was writing the unit tests that should be related to DB manipulation (before downvoting I don't want to test LINQ to Object since the behavior from Linq to SQL can be different, what approach do you use? Do you use a DB replicated from some test environment when I've to test or do you use an in-memory DB? (SQL Express for example?)

Consider the case I've to test an insert in a table where I've got a constraint in the name, testing in SQL to Object wouldn't fail. I was evaluating to have a SqlServer express filled with the data I need to perform the test, for example, if I need to test Customer and Orders with those 2 columns filled) but this would mean that I'll have to create a lot of SQL Server instances to handle all my tests.

What's the best approach?
Thanks

## UPDATE 1

Example of an insert Method I've

```
 public bool InsertUteCliente(UteCliente uteCli)
    {

        UPC upc = new UPC();
        upc.IdUtente = uteCli.idUte;
        upc.CodiceCliente = GetCodCliente(uteCli.id);
        upc.AnagraficaVitaEnable = uteCli.AnagVita;
        upc.AnagraficaRSMEnable = uteCli.AnagRSM;
        upc.AnagraficaInfortuniEnable = uteCli.AnagInfo;
        upc.AnagraficaIPMEnable = uteCli.AnagIPM;
        upc.PolizzaVitaEnable = uteCli.PolVita;
        upc.PolizzaRSMEnable = uteCli.PolRSM;
        upc.PolizzaInfortuniEnable = uteCli.PolInfo;
        upc.PolizzaIPMEnable = uteCli.PolIPM;
        upc.ConsuntiviEnable = uteCli.IfConsuntivi;
        upc.RinnoviEnable = uteCli.IfRinnovi;
        upc.IncEscEnable = uteCli.IfIncEsc;
        upc.PremiVisible = false;
        upc.EstrazionePremiVisibile = uteCli.IfEstrazionePremi;

        dbContext.UPC.Add(upc);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();


        return true;
    }
```

How should I test it?

Comment: What you've described are **integration tests**. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Consider please the update#1 I've set, how would you test it?

Comment: Depends on what it is you want to test. What are you trying to assert in the method under test? That a `DbContext` does what it was designed to do?

Comment: dbcontext is the entity framework dbcontext... willing to test the fact that the dbcontext work I should use a db, but as u told that's an integration test